# CSS Sprite generation in gradle build process?

Tags: css, build, build-process, css-sprites

I recently read an article about Javascript, where Build Tools like Grunt and Ender were mentioned. It was briefly stated, that such tools are capable of generating sprite images from individually provided files and that these build tools can be integrated into the build process.

Unfortunately my google searches didn't unveil more information on this.
Does anybody here have experience on this topic and integration into gradle?
Some web resources for further reading are highly welcome!

Many thanks in advance!
Sascha.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Gradle because you're using Gradle already or are you interested in automated sprite generation in general?  Compass, an extension for Sass, also has automated sprite generation.

Comment: Yes, we are currently building up a Jenkins CI Server running gradle build tasks. In addition, our CSS is based on less (not Sass)...

Answer (score 1):

@Windwalker you might be interested in using the SmartSprites Maven Repositry in your gradle. It takes individual images and creates a sprite image using that along with the required CSS.

The details for the repository can be found at: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.carrotsearch/smartsprites/0.2.8

To install it into your project simply put the following line in your gradle commands :

```
'com.carrotsearch:smartsprites:0.2.8'
```

The full details about the

As the website of Smart Sprite [ http://csssprites.org/ ] says:

> SmartSprites will let you easily introduce and maintain CSS sprites in
>   your designs. SmartSprites parses special directives you can insert
>   into your original CSS to mark individual images to be turned into
>   sprites. It then builds sprite images from the collected images and
>   automatically inserts the required CSS properties into your style
>   sheet, so that the sprites are used instead of the individual images

I hope this solves your situation.

Comment: @Jawad you can check the answer I have written, as it might solve your situation.

Comment: I notice that SmartSprites has an Ant task; Gradle will be able to use that directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://csssprites.com/
http://spritegen.website-performance.org/
http://css-sprit.es/
```

A few online tools that will generate the sprites along with the CSS code.