# Any good alternatives to CSS sprites?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, image, sprite

I'm working on an app that needs to load a lot of icons. At the moment I'm using `<img>` tags with the `src`'s set to the right URLs. That triggers a lot of request. Even if caching is properly set up there are still a lot of HEAD requests.

I'm looking for a solution that will trigger only a minimum of requests (best would be 1) to receive all of the needed icons. But I don't like the concept of spriting, since it's harder to change/replace/add icons in this concept.

Are there any other solutions?

For example, would it be to slow to base64-encode all images to one file on the server, send them to the browser, split them with JavaScript and set base64 src's to the img tags?

Does anyone test this or different approaches?

Comment: But CSS Sprites were made for the eaxact reason "only a minimum of requests (best would be 1)" - http://demosthenes.info/blog/391/CSS-Sprites-for-the-Modern-Era-Refined-Animated-and-Semantic

Comment: It would most definitely be slower than using a pre-rendered sprite sheet.

Comment: There are a few posts if you search Google on this. One I believe by Paul Irish. Here's another decent one http://tjrus.com/blog/base64-vs-css-sprites-battle-for-performance

Comment: So you're trying to say that base64-encode all images, send to browser, split with javascript (what if js will be disabled) is much easier then just create a sprite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554926/css-sprite-generation-in-gradle-build-process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline the images in the CSS using the Base64 data-URIs.

```
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,.......');
```

You can convert your images using a custom PHP/node.js/… script or use an online converter such as http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64

or
https://www.useotools.com/image-to-base64

This results in only one HTTP request being made (only the one for the CSS file) but you cannot control caching for each of the inlined resource individually. You need to set up caching HTTP headers for the CSS file.

You can have your server encode the icons on each request for the CSS file so that you don't need to manually re-convert your icons every time you change them. Some simple caching for the conversion should be included on the server-side.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of an alternative, why not try an icon font? There are some good free ones here:

https://pictonic.co/free

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is I already have a set of icons that perfectly fit, so that's not an option in this case. Nevertheless +1

Comment: You mean it's not an option because you don't want to turn your current icons in to an icon font ([info](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont/)) :)

Comment: actually yes :) I want to keep it simple for users to add their own icons.. it's for a web server index if you are interested: http://larsjung.de/h5ai/

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the creation of CSS sprites on the fly with [CSS sprite](http://code.google.com/p/csssprite/)

Make sure to build the sprites and save them on the server before your client requests them or on the first client request as you add much unnecessary overhead if you generate a sprite sheet on every request.

This allows you to have the images as separate files and just execute a script on the server to create those pesky sprite sheets, leaving the originals intact and making updating them a breeze. (Requires PHP built with the imagemagick library)

**Note:** I am not sure how efficient at distributing the images CSS sprite is.